# Given two maps, how to find the common keys between the two?

Tags: go

I have two structs, Employee and Project.

```
type Employee struct {
    ID        int
    Projects map[*Departments]struct{}
}

type Project struct {
        ID        int
}
```

I have a Company struct that has the following:

```
type Company struct {
  Projects     map[*Project]map[*Employee]struct{}
  Employees       map[*Employee]struct{}
}
```

Given `e *Employee` and `c *Company` (`func (c *Company) getEmployeesOnSameProject(e *Employee) []*Employee { }` )and knowing that an employee can belong to multiple projects, I am having a difficult time figuring out how to get the employees across projects.

`e.Projects` might be something like -

```
eProjects {
  P1
  P2
}
```

`c.Projects` might be something like -

```
cProjects {
  P1 {
    E1
    E2
  }
  P2 {
    E1
    E2
    E3
    E4
  }
}
```

If I am E1, how can I easily get the other employees on the same projects (P1 and P2) as me without having a nested for loop?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, in an idea world you'd like to be able to lookup *"employees for a given project"* as well as *"projects for a given employee"*?

Without knowing the context that you will be using this code in; e.g. more writes than reads, more reads than writes, what the space vs. time complexity requirements are.

If you are aiming for O(1) lookup for projects for an employee and O(1) lookup for employees for a project, then I would suggest creating your own datastructure to be able to facilitate this. This is the smallest interface that would work:

```
type ProjectEmployees interface {
    RegisterProjectEmployee(p *Project, e *Employee)
    GetEmployees(p *Project) []*Employees
    GetProjects(e *Employee) []*Project
}
```

I haven't listed a full implementation below as it would be trivial to work out, but you'd implement this interface with a struct that store 2 maps.

The tradeoff is that you have a larger write / update cost, and data duplication, the benefit is O(1) lookups in both directions `Project <--> Employee`.

```
type projecEmployeesMap struct {
    pe map[*Project][]*Employee
    ep map[*Employee][]*Project
}

func (p *projectEmployeesMap) RegisterProjectEmployee(p *Project, e *Employee) {
    p.pe[p] = append(p.pe[p], e) // store the mapping project -> employees
    p.ep[e] = append(p.ep[e], p) // store the mapping employees --> project
}
```

The get methods should be easy to implement with simple map lookups

Comment: Thanks.  I guess the duplication issue is always gonna be a problem right?  What if I just create a new map, like `map[*Employee]struct{}` and build up that by iterating over each Company.Projects[e.Project] ?  That way, I am guaranteed to not get duplicates for my keys, and iterate over that?

Comment: Just asking because the de-dupe would be costly as well haha.

Comment: Yes, if you are talking about a `Get` where the list returned is essentially a set, then yes, you could use a map to dedupe. Feel free to modify the example above in anyway that would benefit you. There's no reason to say that the return types of `Get` must be slices. They could easily be other datastructures.